# add Table to database

Tags: magento2, database, declarative-schema

I want add new table to DB
This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="acme_ponumber_sales_order" engine="innodb" comment="Sales orders">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="order_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Order id"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="po_number" comment="Po number"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>

        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="ACME_PONUMBER_SALES_ORDER_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID" table="acme_ponumber_sales_order" column="order_id" referenceTable="sales_order" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

next  run code

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Acme_PoNumber
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I check database but the table not create. I check with localhost

Comment: Have you create db_schema.xml file inside Vendor/Module/etc/ ?

Comment: Did you enable your module?

Answer (score 0):

Add "`resource`" node in table

Replace

```
<table name="acme_ponumber_sales_order" engine="innodb" comment="Sales orders">
```

With this

```
<table name="acme_ponumber_sales_order" resource="default" engine="innodb"
           comment="Sales orders Table">
```

Comment: Is it working ?